# iPhone leak on this line, why?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

I am getting a leak on this line and I'm not sure why...

weather.condition = [weather.condition lowercaseString];

weather is a NSMutableArray with a load of NSStrings in? Is there anything obviously wrong with this line or is it a bigger issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you have to learn about detecting memory leaks, is that leaks doesn't detect the line the leak occurs on per say, it detects where the object that is leaking was retained/copied/created. You need to look elsewhere for the actual leak, posting more code would be helpful. I'll update this answer if you do. Please comment below to indicate you've updated the answer with more code.

Comment: Of course you are right! I've nearly finished my app so the code is complicated, you hint has made me look into it further though so hopefully I'll have that leak mopped up soon!

Answer (score 0):

I remember i had this problem when i was using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString and i had to declare a new string to hold it in, rather than perform it on itself if that makes any sense!:)

Answer (score 0):

If weather.condition is a synthesized retain property, then you could probably get away with that statement without a leak because the synthesized setCondition method will check to see if there is a value assigned to condition, and release it. If you wrote the setCondition method, you are responsible for managing the memory associated with condition.